# Unable to set response header Connection to "close" in aspnet core 2.2

Tags: iis, .net-core, header, asp.net-core-2.2, kestrel-http-server

I have a scenario where I want to shut down a aspnet core web server gracefully. The idea is that we at a certain point set response header Connection: close and then when there is no more open connections the web server is shut down.

We add the header via a middleware. Other headers are added just fine, but Connection doesn't seem to be able to be changed.
We do something similar with a aspnet 4.7 and in that application it work just fine to set the response header to close using a ActionFilterAttribute.

I have used fiddler to see if the header is there but it doesn't show there either.

Is it not possible to set the connection header in the response in aspnet core 2.2?

```
public class ResponseHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IConfig _config;

    public ResponseHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfig config)
    {
        _next = next;
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
            if (_config.HttpSendConnectionClose)
            {
                httpContext.Response?.Headers.Add("Connection", new string[] { "close" });
            }
            //Header that is added just fine.
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Site", "Simple-Talk");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }, context);

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the IConfig  in your middlewire? I found you check the _config.HttpSendConnectionClose firstly. I guess the result of the _config.HttpSendConnectionClose is false, so it doesn't add the connection header. I suggest you could try to set a breakpoint to  debug it.

Comment: It is just an injected service, and the HttpSendConnectionClose boolean is set to true when we want to add the connection: close header. If we set any other random header in the same if-clause it appears in the response

Comment: I wasn't using InProcess hosting on IIS, when I changed to that the header seems to be coming along.

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about your server? Do you use sevice to host your asp.net core application or something else?  I have run the test on IIS and it contains the connection header.